Lookup Previous Cell Value in Excel
I need some help in creating an excel formula where it will lookup the previous code based on the column name. Please my sample data below:
Column A and B is being added on file daily, what I'm trying to do is lookup a value in column B and return the previous column A value to Column C. If it doesn't have a previous column A value, it will return blank.

I'm currently doing manual entry for this process. I tried searching for similar case but I can't find any. appreciate your help.

=XLOOKUP(B5,B$2:B4,A$2:A4,,0,-1)?

when i use the formula, it's only returning either the first or last number. I tried to play with it and still not get the desired output. thank you.

In your question you did not specify what column the lookup values is in and what column the return values is in.

Sorry, the lookup value is column B. and the return values are in column A. I want to return the previous code values to column C.

Works as expected: https://i.sstatic.net/zYqNoG5n.png

oh I got it, sorry let me try again. i think i locked B4 and A4 as well.
